# Textbox not showing new text value from database update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have textboxes that I load with data from the database when the page is first loaded and after a database update. Here is some of the code. From the vb code-behind:

```
Private Sub doLoad()
    Dim dvsqlClient As DataView
    dvsqlClient = CType(sqlClient.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    toptxtCliName.Text = CType(dvsqlClient.Table.Rows(0)("ClientName"), String)
    txtCliName.Text = CType(dvsqlClient.Table.Rows(0)("ClientName"), String)
    '    load the rest of the textboxes
End Sub
```

After saving the input data, this code runs:

```
'    code that saves to database
'    show confirmation
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "generateSuccess", "generate('Client Saved.', 'success', 'center');", True)
'    load everything again
doLoad()
```

From the aspx page:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" Width="100%">
<asp:TableRow BackColor="LightGray">
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TextBox ID="toptxtCliName" Enabled="false" CssClass="big_textbox textbox-disabled" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" TabStripPlacement="Top">
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="ClientPanel" HeaderText="Client Info">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="right_column" colspan="5">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliName" TabIndex="1" runat="server" CssClass="big_textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

My datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlClient" runat="server"
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:xConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT ClientName
                     FROM view_Client
                    WHERE ClientCode = @ClientCode">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="CLICODE" Name="ClientCode">
        </asp:QueryStringParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The first time through, and after refreshes, both text boxes show the same, correct, value. After running the save sub and running doLoad again. toptxtCliName.text still holds the previous value while txtCliName.text holds the new value. When I put a breakpoint on the boxes in the code-behind, the code shows that both textboxes are filled with the same text. But when the window comes back up, only txtCliName.text has the correct value. If I hit refresh, they both have the correct value when the page finishes loading.

As far as I can tell, it's the exact same code. Can anyone else see something I'm missing?

It's happening on two of my pages, same structure as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say 100% without seeing all the code, but my guess is that you are hitting the server on an ajax callback and thus only the content within the UpdatePanel can be modified.

toptxtCliName needs to be inside an UpdatePanel based on what you are trying to accomplish. Try placing both controls within the UpdatePanel and see if that helps.  Some other choices would be using two UpdatePanels, or possibly moving the UpdatePanel higher so that it starts immediately before the TableRow.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem. The next problem is that I can't have that upper row of textboxes inside the tabcontainer. They're at the top, outside of the tabcontainer, to match the original application's format. Do I need an updatepanel for them?

Comment: The "easiest" fix is probably to move the opening tag for UpdatePanel to the first line of code, then the entire table would be inside the UpdatePanel.  However, if the table is large, this will cause a lot of data to move between client and server on every ajax callback.

If the table is very large, it might make more sense to use JQuery or pure javascript to make the update call and then update the DOM client-side, this would require a bit of a change in your overall approach.

Comment: It's a large table, holding a tabcontainer with three tabs, many textboxes on the first and repeaters on the second and third. I've got an autocomplete `input type=text` box that I can't seem to figure out, too. I know next to nothing about javascript or JQuery. Would putting the tabcontainer inside the updatepanel work okay?

Comment: toptxtCliName needs to be inside an UpdatePanel based on what you are trying to accomplish.  So, simply moving the TabContainer inside the UpdatePanel will not work.  Some other choices would be using two UpdatePanels, or possibly moving the UpdatePanel higher so that it starts immediately before the TableRow.

Comment: I put an UpdatePanel in the TableCell that txtCliName is in, put that textbox in it, and it worked fine. If you put your comment as the answer, I will accept that. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer, does it now capture all the relevant details from the comments?

Comment: Yes indeed. Accepted.